# How do I resume on the entry thread in an async-Main?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm using C# 7.3 with an `async Task Main()` entrypoint in a WPF application. I'm implementing my own `Main` method so I can safely run some `async` methods prior to entering into the WPF-generated `Application.Main` method (because using `async` code in `OnStartup` doesn't work for my situation).

The problem is that WPF needs the main entry thread (an STA thread, I note) to be the thread that calls `Application.Run` (via `Application.Main`). But I don't know how to get `await` to resume on the entry thread. I assumed that because I didn't specify `.ConfigureAwait(false)` that it would be forced to resume on the same thread but now I know this is only the case when a non-default `SynchronizationContext` is established, like in WPF and WinForms, which doesn't exist yet in my code (`System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` returns `null`).

Here's my code:

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static async Task Main(String[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        await XmlDocumentConfigurationService.Instance.LoadConfigAsync();

        RegisterDependencies( SimpleIoc.Default );

        MyApplication.Main(); // fails because now the thread is not the entry thread
    }
}
```

MyApplication.xaml.cs / MyApplication.g.i.cs (WPF generated):

```
/// <summary>
/// Application Entry Point.
/// </summary>
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
public static void Main() {
    MyApplication app = new MyApplication();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

I know I could use Stephen Cleary's `AsyncEx` library's `AsyncContext` class to run my async code synchronously, but that defeats the point of using `async Main` - and adds another set of dependencies:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

    AsyncContext.Run( XmlDocumentConfigurationService.Instance.LoadConfigAsync );

    RegisterDependencies( SimpleIoc.Default );

    MyApplication.Main();
}
```

#### Update: Attempt using `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`:

As this is a WPF application, I thought I'd try using `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext`:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
DispatcherSynchronizationContext context = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext( dispatcher );
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext( context );

await XmlDocumentConfigurationService.Instance.LoadConfigAsync();

// (execution never gets here)
RegisterDependencies( SimpleIoc.Default );

MyApplication.Main();
```

...unfortunately execution gets to the `await` statement but never continues afterwards. I'm assuming this is because I haven't wired-up the Dispatcher to the Win32 message loop - and I'm not sure if I want to do that myself as WPF will do it by itself inside `app.Run();`.

Comment: [There is always a SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

Comment: @RonBeyer But `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current == null` when I run my program.

Comment: From the linked article: *"By convention, if a thread’s current SynchronizationContext is null, then it implicitly has a default SynchronizationContext.*"

Comment: There is no gain here in calling LoadConfigAsync() over just LoadConfig(), if you have that. Otherwise, just use a `.Wait()` here. Or that GetAwaiter() variation. Make Main non-async again.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Doesn't that run the risk of entering a deadlock situation?

Comment: `.Wait()` risks deadlock when you call it from an event - inside Application.Run(). This is before that, no problem at all. And there are not other threads to profit from your async implementation yet.

Answer (score -3):

By default, new projects in Visual Studio (2017) only work with the latest major version of the language (which would be 7.0), but you can change that. Please follow this blog of [Ben Willi](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/12/08/async-main-is-available-but-hidden/)